# Why can't I redirect stderr from within a bash -c command line?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm trying to log the time for the execution of a command, so I'm doing that by using the builtin `time` command in bash.  I also wish to redirect the stderr and stdout to a logfile at the same time.  However, it doesn't seem to be working as the stderr just spills out onto my terminal.

Here is the command:

```
rm -rf doxygen
mkdir doxygen
bash -c 'time "/cygdrive/d/Program Files/doxygen/bin/doxygen.exe" Doxyfile > doxygen/doxygen.log 1>&2' genfile > doxygen/time 1>&2 &
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `1>&2` instead of `2>&1`.

With the lengths of names reduced, you're trying to run:

```
bash -c 'time doxygen Doxyfile > doxygen.log 1>&2' genfile > doxygen.time 1>&2 &
```

The `> doxygen.log` sends standard output to the file; the `1>&2` then changes your mind and sends standard output to the same place that standard error is going.  Similarly with the outer pair of redirections.

If you used:

```
bash -c 'time doxygen Doxyfile > doxygen.log 2>&1' genfile > doxygen.time 2>&1 &
```

then you send standard error to the same place that standard output goes — twice.

Incidentally, do you realize that the `genfile` serves as the `$0` for the script run by `bash -c '…'`?  I'm not convinced it is needed in your script.  To see this, try:

```
bash -c 'echo 0=$0; echo 1=$1; echo 2=$2' genfile jarre oxygene
```

When run, this produces:

```
0=genfile
1=jarre
2=oxygene
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't paying attention.  Thanks.  `you send standard error to the same place that standard output goes — twice`.  Yeah, the bash shell will not output the time to the inner redirect.  It has to be redirected external to that.  As for the `genfile`, that was by... instinct? (not exactly the word I'm looking for).

Comment: The comment about 'twice' was strictly recognizing that the same notation was needed twice; it was not a criticism of its presence since, as you say, Bash's time is reluctant to be redirected.  The `genfile` does no harm, but it also provides no benefit.  Is 'autopilot' a synonym for the term you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah, that's it, I was on autopilot. It's reluctant because bash had its own stdout which isn't affected. The newly spawned process are given copies of the shells, and redirection only affects the copies, not the originals. So anything that bash outputs goes there.